# Is it possible to edit certain property values in the Principled Shader when using a Normal map as a Bump map?

Tags: texturing, shaders, normals, normal-map

What I mean by this is for example, if I connect the normal map into the Metallic property of the Principled shader, is it possible to change the intensity or the amount of impact that the Normal map has on the property? If so, how do I go about doing it?[image: I want to change the Roughness value]

Comment: Do not connect Normal map anywhere but Normal input of the shaders. Roughness map is expected to be black and white (if even used, as in some cases glossy / specular maps used instead). As to controlling amount of normal map effect use slider in Normal map node.

Comment: A math node can be used to multiply a value - x0.5 is half strength. A colour ramp node is also a commonly used, it allows you to affect the amount differently over the range of values. Note that the vector from the normal map is three values, the roughness only uses one, You can use a separate xyz node to get each value, maybe calc an average or use only one value.